# Filling a circle produced by Midpoint Algorithm

Tags: python, math

In python, I have written some code that generates a circle using Bresenham's Midpoint Algorithm:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
radius = 100 #radius of circle
xpts = [] #array to hold x pts
ypts = [] #array to hold y pts
img = Image.new('RGB', (1000, 1000))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img) #to use draw.line()
pixels = img.load()
d = (5/4) - radius
x = 0
y = radius
xpts.append(x) #initial x value
ypts.append(y) #initial y value

while x < y:
 if d < 0:
    d += (2*x + 3)
    x += 1
    xpts.append(x + 500) #translate points to center by 500px
    ypts.append(y - 500) 
 else:
    d += (2 * (x - y) + 5)
    x += 1
    y -= 1
    xpts.append(x + 500) #translate points to center by 500px
    ypts.append(y - 500)


for i in range(len(xpts)): #draw  initial and reflected octant points
   pixels[xpts[i] ,ypts[i]] = (255,255,0) #initial octant
   pixels[xpts[i],-ypts[i]] = (255,255,0)
   pixels[-xpts[i],ypts[i]] = (255,255,0)
   pixels[-xpts[i],-ypts[i]] = (255,255,0)
   pixels[ypts[i],xpts[i]] = (255,255,0)
   pixels[-ypts[i],xpts[i]] = (255,255,0)
   pixels[ypts[i],-xpts[i]] = (255,255,0)
   pixels[-ypts[i],-xpts[i]] = (255,255,0)




img.show()
```

To fill it, I had planned to use ImageDraw to draw a line horizontally within the circle from each point that is generated from the initial octant using draw.line(). I have the x and y coordinates stored in arrays. However, I am stuck interpreting each point and its reflection point to draw the horizontal line using draw.line(). Could someone clarify this?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of drawing individual pixels, you would just add a line that connects the pixels corresponding to each other (either -x and +x or -y and +y). For each Bresenham step, you draw four lines (each connecting two octants).

Here is your adapted sample code. I dropped the points array and instead drew the lines directly. I also added the `cx` and `cy` variables that define the circle center. In your code, you sometimes used negative indices. This only works by coincidence because the circle is in the center:

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

radius = 100  # radius of circle
xpts = []  # array to hold x pts
ypts = []  # array to hold y pts
img = Image.new('RGB', (1000, 1000))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)  # to use draw.line()
pixels = img.load()
d = (5 / 4) - radius
x = 0
y = radius

cx = 500
cy = 500


def draw_scanlines(x, y):
    color = (255, 255, 0)
    draw.line((cx - x, cy + y, cx + x, cy + y), fill=color)
    draw.line((cx - x, cy - y, cx + x, cy - y), fill=color)
    draw.line((cx - y, cy + x, cx + y, cy + x), fill=color)
    draw.line((cx - y, cy - x, cx + y, cy - x), fill=color)


draw_scanlines(x, y)

while x < y:
    if d < 0:
        d += (2 * x + 3)
        x += 1
    else:
        d += (2 * (x - y) + 5)
        x += 1
        y -= 1

    draw_scanlines(x, y)

img.show()
```

Comment: Note that the lines `cx - x, cy + y, cx + x, cy + y` (and `...- y`, being the top and bottom quarters of the circle) are drawn multiple times superimposed, as `y` changes less frequently then `x`. This goes against the speed idea for which Bresenham algorithms were created. Also, it can be problematic when drawing transparent shapes.

Comment: Oh, you are right. I didn't pay attention to that. I'll update the code eventually. In the meantime, if you have a better solution, feel free to post it as well.

Comment: The basic idea would be to always draw the lines for a given x, and only draw the lines for y at the start of the `else` part (to catch the largest x). But testing it and being sure that everything is perfect, can be tricky.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of drawing lines, you can fill all points inside a circle with radius `radius` in `O(n^2)` using:

```py
# Your code here 

for x in range(radius):
    for y in range(radius):
        if x**2 + y**2 < radius**2:
            pixels[  x + 500 ,  y-500] = (255,255,0)
            pixels[  x + 500 , -y-500] = (255,255,0)
            pixels[ -x + 500 ,  y-500] = (255,255,0)
            pixels[ -x + 500 , -y-500] = (255,255,0)

img.show()
```

[image]